# h1 is too low in the element

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* main elements */
div.body    {
    display: block;
    background-color: Lavender; 
    border: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
body    {
    display: block;
    background-color: Lavender; 
    border: 10px;
    max-width:1100px;
    margin: 0px 280px 0px 10px;
    clear:both;
}
/*Body Divs*/
div.bodycontent{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 1075px;
    height: 470px;
    background-color: MediumAquaMarine;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0px;
    bottom:10px;
}
div.body1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: limegreen;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width:480px;
    height:225px;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
div.body2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: Salmon;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width:525px;
    height:225px;
    margin-left:520px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
div.body3 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: FireBrick;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    width:530px;
    height:205px;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
div.body4 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: SeaGreen;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    width:475px;
    height:205px;
    margin-left:570px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

header {
    background-color: Lavender;
}
/*header divs*/
div.header {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width: 1075px;
    height:150px;
    top:490px;
    background-color: PaleGoldenRod;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
div.backinfo {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    top:80px;
    width:455px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height:40px;
    margin-right:900px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
div.digitalbay {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: coral;
    position: absolute;
    width:455px;
    height:60px;
    top:20px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-right:560px;
    margin-left:180px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  }
div.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightblue;
    top:10px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-left:665px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    height:110px;
    width:395px;
}
div.contact {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: Chocolate;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width:300px;
    height:45px;
    margin-right:550px;
    margin-left:190px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
div.contact2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: DeepPink;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width:130px;
    height:45px;
    margin-right:550px;
    margin-left:515px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="bodydiv">
    <header>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="backinfo">
            </div>
            <div class="digitalbay">
                <h1>Digital Bay</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
            </div>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="bodycontent">
            <div class="body1">
            </div>
            <div class="body2">
            </div>
            <div class="body3">
            </div>
            <div class="body4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</div>
<aside>
    <div class="extrainfo">
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow">
    </div>
</aside>
<footer>
    <div  class="footer">
    </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

In the elements above, where my `<div class=digitalbay>`element is located when compiled, the `<h1>`element nested in the div is too low in the element when compiled. I was wondering if there is a way to make it higher up the `div`. I already tried changing the margin, but it moves the div up along the page and that doesn't help.

Comment: Why do you have 3 levels of nesting : div within div within div ? With only one line of content ?

Comment: do you use a reset css style sheet ? if not, you may reset h1 margins to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a margin on the `h1` and it will move up. Example:

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.header` div has a `top: 490px`. That is why it is so low.

On other note, here's a bit of feedback on your CSS and HTML.

- Never put the `<body>` tag inside a `<div>`... it is always supposed to be right after the `<head>` tag. When the browser parses the HTML, it'll auto correct that for you, but you will have bugs if you start expecting your body tag to be where it is now.
- Don't write your CSS as follow `div.className`. Instead, simply use the class name without the element: `.className`. This will reduce specificity and make it easier to maintain as it grows. It'll also dramatically reduce your typing.
- I don't know what your goal is in the end with this page, but it may be easier to not use `position: absolute` everywhere. Use `position: relative` instead.
- In HTML, there is a tag called `<main>`. There can only be one per page, and I use it instead of your `<div class="bodydiv">`.
- You are using `<header>` and `<footer>` and putting a `<div>` inside of it with a class of header and footer... Remove that and put your class directly on the `<header>` and `<footer>` tag.
- Inside your `<div class="bodycontent">`, you could use the `<section>` tag instead of DIVs (if it is semantically correct in your case).